# What is "Utility" Configuration type in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio, Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Project Defaults -> Configuration Type has {Makefile, Application(.exe), Dynamic Library(.dll), Static Library(.lib) and ***Utility***} choices.
What are the intended uses of the ***Utility*** type projects; could you please point me to some documentation?
Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Utility projects are empty projects and do not have any predefined outputs. We have to write our custom build rules.

Documentation Link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733962(v=vs.60).aspx

> When you create a utility project, no files are added to the project. 
>   The utility project does not generate any predetermined output files,
>   such as a .LIB, .DLL or .EXE.  A utility project can be used as a
>   container for files you can build without a link step:
>
> - You can use a utility project as a master project for your
>     subprojects.
> - A utility project can export a MAKEFILE.
> - A utility project has nothing but custom build rules; you must create
>     custom build rules and add files.
> - Utility projects respect the list of specified outputs and checks to
>     see if outputs are out of date.

Comment: I'd like to add that this is IMHO the only way to have utility behaviour in visual studio, even for C# developers. BUT you need the **C++ Workload** installed on the machine. Most C# devs apparently don't, which will cause issues finding `Microsoft.Cpp.*` build targets.

Comment: @Samuel Thanks for that. I spent half an hour looking on why I couldn't add utility projects since I'd wiped my machine. Here I go filling the hard drive again...

Comment: The documentation link was last updated 2006 and has a notice saying it's no longer valid. Also it says that in order to create a Utility project, you create a DLL project but then gives no further direction